# Claims transformation ClaimsAuthenticationManager with Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wif, claims-based-identity, thinktecture-ident-model

I am looking to write a MVC5 application that uses Windows Authentication.

As per the boilerplate code the `@User.Identity.Name` claims are populated automatically.

I would like to transform incoming claims with my own logic and enrich them so roles are assigned for users:

```
class SimpleClaimsAuthenticatonManager : ClaimsAuthenticationManager
{
    public override ClaimsPrincipal Authenticate(string resourceName, ClaimsPrincipal incomingPrincipal)
    {
        if (incomingPrincipal != null && incomingPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated == true)
        {
            ((ClaimsIdentity)incomingPrincipal.Identity).AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "User"));
        }
        return incomingPrincipal; 
    }
}
```

Does Thinktecture identity model library support a way to wire up the above custom AuthenticationManager in to the MVC5 pipeline?